# change the order of elements inside a DIV tag

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to change the order of elements inside a `div` dinamically in specific condition.

The original code is

```html
<div class="radio radio-inline radio-primary">
  <input 
    id="allergyYes" 
    type="radio" 
    (click)="toggleAllergy($event)" 
    data-toggle="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="allergy.isAllergic" 
    [value]="1"
    name="allergyYes" 
  />
  <label for="allergyYes">{{selectedLanguage.yes}}</label>
</div>
```

And when a variable changes, I would like the order inside the div to be changed to be :

```html
<div class="radio radio-inline radio-primary">
  <label for="allergyYes">{{selectedLanguage.yes}}</label>
  <input 
    id="allergyYes" 
    type="radio" 
    (click)="toggleAllergy($event)" 
    data-toggle="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="allergy.isAllergic" 
    [value]="1"
    name="allergyYes" 
  />
</div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two templates and an [ngif (3rd example in Description section)](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description).

This will display the content in the div if the expression evaluates to `true`, otherwise it will display the content from the `ng-template` if it evaluates to `false`.

```html
<div class="radio radio-inline radio-primary" *ngIf="myVar === 'option-one';else elseBlock">
  <input id="allergyYes" 
    type="radio" 
    (click)="toggleAllergy($event)" 
    data-toggle="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="allergy.isAllergic" 
    [value]="1" 
    name="allergyYes" />
  <label for="allergyYes">{{selectedLanguage.yes}}</label>
</div>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <label for="allergyYes">{{selectedLanguage.yes}}</label>
  <input id="allergyYes" 
    type="radio" 
    (click)="toggleAllergy($event)" 
    data-toggle="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="allergy.isAllergic" 
    [value]="1" 
    name="allergyYes" />
</ng-template>
```

```js
@Component({
  // Component settings
})
export class TestComponent {
  public myVar = 'option-two'
}
```